# Mysql segfaulting when used from the shell

Tags: raspberry-pi, mysql, raspbian, segmentation-fault

I have a Raspberry Pi server with Raspbian OS:

```
Kernel: Linux 4.9.35+ #1014 Fri Jun 30 14:34:49 BST 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie
```

Today I noticed that attempts to use `mysql` end in a segmentation fault.

```
user@host~ $ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Segmentation fault
```

This happens for both the wrong and the right password. Or even if I made up a username. Actually, it turns out than even running the `mysql` command without any arguments has the same effect.

The Mysql server can still be accessed via Python (`pymysql`) and Perl. I have scripts that write and read various DBs, they are all working without problems.

Shell scripts that use the `mysql` command, they all fail. For example:

```
/home/user/example.sh: line 2: 27974 Segmentation fault      /usr/bin/mysql -u dbuser -p$dbpass dbname --execute="select * from example;"
```

The segmentation faults started appearing today and I cannot figure what is causing them now. The server has not been booted in a few weeks. It has been more than a week since it was last updated.

I can't find any errors that might look like relevant to this situation from the Mysql logs or syslog.

I have tried:

- Restarting Mysql
- Upgrading the system and rebooting
- Checking disk on reboot, no errors found

As these procedures didn't help, I tried using `gdb` as suggested here:

[Running application ends with "Segmentation Fault"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132192/running-application-ends-with-segmentation-fault)

This is what I get when debugging the command `mysql` without any parameters:

gdb mysql
run
run
Starting program: /usr/bin/mysql

```
gdb mysql
run
Starting program: /usr/bin/mysql
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
elf_dynamic_do_Rel (skip_ifunc=<optimized out>, lazy=0, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>,
    reladdr=<optimized out>, map=0xb6fff968) at do-rel.h:112
112     do-rel.h: No such file or directory.
```

I wonder what could I do to fix this problem? (Other than making a bug report about this.)

Comment: Has mysql package been upgraded during your upgrade and reboot process?

Comment: Mysql was updated when I last run last normal updates in 2018-02-02. During todays upgrade Mysql didn't get updated.

Comment: I have stated the facts best I could. As I stated in the post, I could not find anything strange from logs. Both OS and the database are on the same SD card. Segmentation fault might be bug in Mysql so I am considering reporting it if I can't other cause for the errors.

Comment: Bug reports usually involve some debugging and knowing technical reasons and *why* you are reporting a bug. They are not meant for user support, I am afraid. Let me try to write an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I meant the bug report as last resort, if I was unable to find anything wrong on my own system.

Comment: They would ask you steps to reproduce the bug in their systems and close the bug. Bug reporting does not normally equates end user support, you have to give the package maintainers/developers sound technical details for opening a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most likely have corrupted binaries/and or a corrupted filesystem/SD card.

The SD cards are not meant for heavy I/O use and degrade over time; Raspberry(es) are also known to corrupt data in SD cards when turning off occasionally due to characteristics of their design (electronics is not my area, not able to get into details).

You might very well have a corruption on the `mysql` binary or associated libraries. (actually having a `gdb` failure at `do-rel.h` suggests the latter).

I would reinstall the `mysql` client and associated libraries, as a command similar to this one (your mileage may vary):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall default-mysql-client default-mysql-client-core
```

I would use this command to see what package is giving you the `mysql` binary and would reinstall it:

```
dpkg -S /usr/bin/mysql
```

Then I would also see what libraries `mysql` is using, if that does not fix the problem:

```
ldd /usr/bin/mysql
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc8903c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5989c75000)
    libreadline.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.5 (0x00007f5989a33000)
    libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007f5989810000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f59895e6000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f59893cc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f59891c8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5988e46000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5988b42000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f59887a3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f598a4bc000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f598858c000)
```

You might have as last resort to reinstall each package supporting each one of this libraries until your have your error corrected. Some of them are: `libaio1`, `libjemalloc1`, `libreadline5`. There are more.

```
sudo apt-get install -reinstall libaio1 libjemalloc1 libreadline5
```

Nevertheless, there are no guarantees you do not have other bits of your filesystem corrupted. I would backup the DB and reinstall the OS/MySQL from scratch.

The good news is that you mentioning other ways of accessing the DB are working well, it means the corruption is mostly related to the `mysql` binary client.

Nonetheless, I would probably reevaluate running Linux from an SD card card in the future, especially if using MySQL.

PS. As @cas points well, "if you have `dlocate` or `debsums` installed, you can run `dlocate --md5check PKGNAME` or `debsums PKGNAME` to verify the package's installed files against its md5sum file"

See [Raspberry: booting from a USB pen instead of an SD card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419155/raspberry-booting-from-a-usb-pen-instead-of-an-sd-card)

Comment: Thanks, reinstalling `mysql-client` made the error disappear and Mysql commands now work without errors. I'll also look replacing SD card and OS reinstallation.

Comment: FYI if you have `dlocate` or `debsums` installed, you can run `dlocate --md5check PKGNAME` or `debsums PKGNAME` to verify the package's installed files against its md5sum file.

Comment: you don't know dlocate? how could you not.? in my completely unbiased opinion it's the best package in debian.  (disclaimer: i am the author).   BTW, IIRC, when I added `--md5check` to dlocate, it was the only tool that could easily verify a package's md5sum files....if you wanted to do that, you had to write your own script.  debsums came later, long after it became standard practice to have .md5sum files in packages.