# lspci run failed

Tags: linux, pci

There is a lspci failed message when I text the lspci command
`lspci`

```
lspci: Line too long at /usr/share/misc/pci.ids, line 1
```

so I try other command to show the line number

`sed -n 1p /usr/share/misc/pci.ids | wc -c`

```
1210291
```

`cat /usr/share/misc/pci.ids | awk '{ print length }' | sort -n  | tail -1`

```
1210291
```

(In the normal machine only get 167)

The machine data is:

- lsb_release -a

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

- uname -r

```
5.11.0-40-generic
```

lspci version:

```
lspci version 3.6.4
```

How do I fix this problem or there is a workaround?

There is samilary discussion in [raspberry pi page](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=312359)

Comment: try `apt install --reinstall pci.ids`

Comment: `same discussion in raspberry pi page` - that's on a different line though

Comment: I mean there is a the same like the link. I modified the question later.

Comment: I understand, but line 1 being over a million bytes is a little different to line 23,610 being "too long" ... your `pci.ids` file seems to be absolutely busted - have you inspected it? it should be plain text. Perhaps this is an indication of a failing sd card (I assume you're running this on a pi)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419155/raspberry-booting-from-a-usb-pen-instead-of-an-sd-card/419156

Comment: @Bravo My Ubuntu 20.04  installed on USB stick. And there is all 1329 good 1 is this problem. You are right. This file look likes not totally a plain text file. Although use `file /usr/share/misc/pci.ids` command get return data text. Maybe this file in this USB is broken I guess.

Comment: have you tried `apt install --reinstall pci.ids`

Comment: It look like something error after this reinstall command. I will try to fix it.
```dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package 'libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common' is missing final newline
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```